# Restricting the access to specific pages

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, security

I'm building a quiz web application.  The functionality of the site is just about complete.  However, I'd like to create a script that allows me to input new quizzes and questions from my web browser as opposed to manually inputting them into the MySQL database using phpMyAdmin.

I want to build a form called `newquiz.php` that will enable me to do the inputting on the browser but I don't want just anyone to come across it and start making changes to my database.  So, **my question is how should I go about limiting access to this specific page?**  In my Head First book they talk about using HTTP authentication but I haven't had any success with that (my attempt here: [Unsucessfully accessing Admin page using HTTP authentication with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771953/unsucessfully-accessing-admin-page-using-http-authentication-with-php)).

I'd love some guidance on this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with quizzing?  This is just the most basic access control question and I'm sure there are 20+ other posts just like it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Have a login function, that checks username/password to something you have stored in something like MySQL. Store the userid in $_SESSION['id'].

Now you can start the limited website with the php=code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) die("you are not able to view this without logging in");
```

and the rest of your code underneath

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use your web server's built-in authentication mechanism. Apache has [.htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html); other web servers have different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One can also redirect to unauthorized user to Website login page to restrict unauthorized access by following:

On any .php page you want to restrict access:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}
else
{
    //continue adding your quiz to your page.
}
```